# не запускается сборка c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, отладка, отладчик

для работы с с# я установил Visual Studio Code 2022, затем установил .NET SDK 6.0.301
дальше в самой Visual Studio Code установил библиотеки: C#, vscode-solution-explorer, MSBuild project tools, после попытался запустить проект и при нажатии на выполнить вылезло такое меню:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
с выбором с помощью чего запустить проект, что бы я не выбрал окно просто пропадает и ничего не происходит

P.S: у меня Windows

Comment: Заходите в папку проекта (там где dll и exe лежит), переходите туда в cmd. Дальше пишите: `dotnet run название_ехе`. Если нужны аргументы в метод Main: `dotnet run название_exe арг1 арг2 аргN`

Comment: про какой dll и exe вы говорите? у меня в проекте только test.cs

Comment: Вы неправильно создали проект, [вот гайд](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-6-0) как сделать правильно. Одного cs файла мало для запуска, сначала нужно сбилдить проект в dll а затем уже запустить

Comment: А вообще - лучше юзайте Visual Studio, там есть всё что нужно для работы с C#, VSCode не очень удобен для C#

Comment: спасибо, оказалось проблема лишь в том что я не так создаю проект, благодарю